# Removing first 3 Items from a list

Tags: c#

How can I remove n items together from a List?

For example in a List of 10 elements I want to remove 3 items together using a for cicle

Comment: Do you want to use the 3 items or do you want them to be gone from your list?

Comment: I would advice to include some code of what you have tried. It will increase the chances of getting an answer and reduce the chances of having your question flagged and removed.

Comment: Ok thanks. Problem solved. Next time I will include some code

Comment: You should accept the answer that solved your issue, so this question gets marked as solved.

Answer (score 11):

If you want to safely remove the first three items:

```
list.RemoveRange(0, Math.Min(3, list.Count));
```

That will remove up to three items, but won't throw an exception if there are fewer than three items in the list. If there are 0, 1, or 2 items in the list it will remove that many.

Answer (score 5):

#### Edit

To process a slice of a list/array without modifying it in C# 8 or above, I suggest using [Ranges](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#indices-and-ranges).

#### Original

To enumerate a list without the first n elements (in case you don't want to modify the list) you can use [`Skip`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.skip).

```
// this will take all the elements except for the first three (these will be skipped).
IEnumerable<SomeThing> withoutFirstThree = list.Skip(3);
```

Skip also goes well with [`Take`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.take) if you don't want to enumerate to the end of the list. As mentioned in the Docs of Skip:

> The Take and Skip methods are functional complements. Given a sequence coll and an integer n, concatenating the results of coll.Take(n) and coll.Skip(n) yields the same sequence as coll.

If you want to have a `List` instead of an `IEnumerable` you can use `.ToList()` on the `Enumerable` you get back but then this approach may not be suitable for your use case.

If you instead want to *modify* the list, you can use [`RemoveRange`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.removerange) as other answers already suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove first 3 items?

```
list.RemoveRange(0, 3);
```

Removes 3 items starting at `index=0`.